# How to recover data from crashed Windows laptop?

Tags: windows-8, testdisk, portable-ubuntu-remix

Below are the step wise events that occurred to me:

1. My system goes into hang state.
2. A pop up appears which says "something went wrong, collecting information".
3. After 20 seconds it shuts down.
4. Then it never restarted again.
5. On trying to reinstall new Windows; my whole hard disk is shown as free 450 GB. Originally I had 3 partitions: C:, D: and E:.
6. I have tried using Ubuntu rescue remix but it never started.
7. I was not able to install and use testdisk.

My Questions:

1. Is there any slightest possibility to recover my data?
2. If you have any knowledge on recovering data?

_____________________________________New Update_______

A) I connected my HDD to different system using USB to SATA cable

1. Its not making any tik tik sound which it makes in case of damage.
2. Its not able to detect HDD even though i can sense HDD it rotating when i touch it

B) I finally decided to format it & reinstall OS

1. I tried install ubuntu but it didn't succeed for 1 hour
2. so i decided to install windows, but windows was not able to neither format it not install windows

   Windows could not format a partition on disk 0. Error code: 0x80070057

so i used following steps to format it

diskpart

list disk

select disk 0

clean

format

but it couldn't execute format

Answer (score 0):

Do you have system backup in Acronis True Image or smth?

Otherwise

You may recover HDD through some paid third party tools like Recuva in General

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance to recover your data. It depends on the reason the problem occurred in the first place.

First and most important thing when you lose data – do not write anything on this drive. If this is your OS drive, then you shouldn't boot of it. Don't try to reinstall OS. You need to remove the drive and connect it to a different machine so you can explore the current state of things, before taking action. Running multiple data recovery software may sometimes worsen the situation.

If there is physical damage on the HDD chances are you won't be able to retrieve any data yourself. If that is the case you should contact a data recovery company. Usually it easy to tell when there is physical failure as the drive will start making unusual noises.

If something went wrong with the partition table you might be able to restore data using partition recovery software. There is also a variety of data recovery applications, but that would be the last thing to try. 
Provide as much information as possible about the issue. Did you make any changes to your system before it failed? Have you by any chance converted your disc from basic to dynamic? When tried reinstalling did you format the drive? DIY recovering data is not an easy task and not as successful as we would like to think. If you have important data the safest way to get it back should be by contacting a data recovery company/specialist.

Comment: 1. I was coping video from my pen drive when this incident occured.
2. I never tried converting my disk to dynamic so hopefully thats not the case
3. while trying reinstalling i didn't format my disk, I aborted the process when it asked me to do so.

Comment: I would at this point connect the HDD to a different system and check what Disc management sees.

Comment: A) I connected my HDD to different system using USB to SATA cable
1. Its not making any tik tik sound which it makes in case of damage.
2. Its not able to detect HDD even though i can sense HDD it rotating when i touch it
B) I finally decided to format it & reinstall OS
1. I tried install ubuntu but it didn't succeed for 1 hour
2. In windows, but windows was not able to neither format it not install windows
 Windows could not format a partition on disk 0. Error code: 0x80070057
so i used following steps to format it
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0
clean 
format
but it couldn't execute format

Comment: A 0x80070057  error would mean that the system reserved partition is damaged. You could try some non windows software to format the drive, there are plenty that would do the job. Some HDD manufacturers have their own utilities that you can use to perform a fill write zeros. This will wipe out the whole HDD and Windows should be able to format it after that. It's also a good idea to run the manufacturers diagnostics to check the HDD's health before doing anything else.

Comment: will defenately try this by end of this weekened & update the output